# How to run uWSGI via upstart in Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, upstart

I follow *[Setting up Django and your web server with uWSGI and nginx](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#make-uwsgi-startup-when-the-system-boots)*, and I have ran

```
sudo uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data
```

mentioned in the [Emperor mode](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#emperor-mode) section successfully. Then, I try to run uWSGI like a daemon. Following [Running uWSGI via Upstart](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Upstart.html#using-the-emperor), I try this routine:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/init/uwsgi.conf
sudo vim /etc/init/uwsgi.conf
```

This is the `uwsgi.conf` file:

```
description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

exec uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data
```

I don't know what else I have missed or there are some errors in the configuration file. Anyway, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/rc.local and add:

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data --master
```